# Scala sample app for Play 2 with Jquery

Tags: jquery, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Can you recommend any working Scala example that is using JQuery and Play 2.0? I only found a simple Java version. I would like to see how I can configure the UI with Jquery and Play templates
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the provided [Scala samples](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/scala) provided with the Play framework.

Especially at the [Zentask sample](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/scala/zentasks), which uses JQuery under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few really simple examples here:
https://github.com/jamesward/play2bars

All of them use jQuery + JSON but there are different persistence options.